# Web scraping data inside a tab using Rselenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to scrape the summary table under Player statistics in the following page:
https://www.sofascore.com/southampton-wolverhampton/dsV

I am trying to use RSelenium for this purpose

Here is my code so far:

```
   rm=rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever ="111.0.5563.64",
                verbose = F,
                port = free_port())
    
    rmDr=rm$client
    rmDr$open()
    rmDr$navigate("https://www.sofascore.com/southampton-wolverhampton/dsV")
    elem <- rmDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//button[@data-tabid="summary"]')
```

Summary data appears when I click the button summary. Hence I used xpath to extract that button as above. But it didnt work.

Could you suggest any alternative way?

Thank you.

This is the error i got:

```
Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@data-tabid="summary"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.65)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-MOGN5AG', ip: '192.168.0.114', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Here is a snapshot:
[image]

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get an error? If so, edit your question and add the full error message as text, properly formatted. If not, explain what you expected to happen that didn't happen, etc.

Comment: I don't see a "Summary" button on the page and a CTRL+F doesn't find any results either. The locator also doesn't find a matching element. We're going to need more description of what button you are trying to click, its location on the page, and maybe even a screenshot with it circled, etc. Are you sure you gave us the right URL? Do we have to be logged into an account or ?

Comment: You forgot to mention that you have to click on the "PLAYER STATISTICS" button before you can see the "Summary" button. Once I did that, your locator works just fine. My guess is that you need to add a wait before clicking because the page loads a lot of data... that button likely doesn't exist at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clicked on the summary tab using this

```
remDr$findElement(using = "css",value = ".fircAT > div:nth-child(2)")$clickElement()
```

Then after the page switched tabs, I pulled the page's html, and then searched for the table node.
Here's the entire code:

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

# define target url
url <- "https://www.sofascore.com/southampton-wolverhampton/dsV"


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4550L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# open the remote driver-------------------------------------------------------
remDr$open()

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)


# click on the summary tab ------------------------------------
remDr$findElement(using = "css",value = ".fircAT > div:nth-child(2)")$clickElement()



# pull the webpage html
# then read it
page_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() 



# find table elements
tables <- page_html %>% html_table()

summary_stats_table <- tables[[1]]
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
summary_stats_table
# A tibble: 32 × 12
   ``    `+`    Goals Assists Tackles Acc. …¹ Duels…² Groun…³ Aeria…⁴ Minut…⁵ Posit…⁶
   <lgl> <chr>  <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 NA    Moham…     0       0       4 22/32 … 11 (7)  6 (4)   5 (3)   90'     D      
 2 NA    Jan B…     0       0       2 19/30 … 6 (6)   2 (2)   4 (4)   90'     D      
 3 NA    Adama…     0       0       1 11/19 … 11 (7)  11 (7)  0 (0)   45'     F      
 4 NA    Craig…     0       0       1 54/61 … 12 (7)  4 (3)   8 (4)   90'     D      
 5 NA    João …     1       0       1 8/11 (… 7 (2)   5 (2)   2 (0)   20'     M      
 6 NA    Ainsl…     0       0       4 24/36 … 10 (9)  7 (6)   3 (3)   90'     D      
 7 NA    James…     0       0       0 35/42 … 8 (4)   5 (1)   3 (3)   90'     M      
 8 NA    João …     0       0       3 10/12 … 4 (3)   4 (3)   0 (0)   45'     M      
 9 NA    Carlo…     1       0       1 22/26 … 14 (4)  13 (4)  1 (0)   79'     M      
10 NA    Hugo …     0       0       1 19/20 … 5 (2)   3 (2)   2 (0)   45'     D      
# … with 22 more rows, 1 more variable: Rating <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names
#   ¹​`Acc. passes`, ²​`Duels (won)`, ³​`Ground duels (won)`, ⁴​`Aerial duels (won)`,
#   ⁵​`Minutes played`, ⁶​Position
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. Is there any reason that this not work for chrome?

Comment: Could you also explain the use of "fircAT > div:nth-child(2)" ? Thank you

Comment: `.fircAT > div:nth-child(2)` clicks on the "PLAYER STATISTICS" button which exposes the Summary panel. It's a CSS selector.... `.fircAT` is a class name (`.` indicates a class), `>` means a child, and `div:nth-child(2)` means the second `(2)` DIV child. While I strongly prefer CSS selectors over XPath, in this case I would use `//div[text()='Player statistics']` because it's human readable. If something on the page changes and my locator breaks, I have a better sense of what I WAS clicking so I can create a new locator... but that's personal preference.

Comment: Also, this works just fine for chrome. His setup probably just has firefox already installed.

Comment: @JeffC, thanks for explaining the selector!  Just curious, why do you prefer CSS selectors?

Comment: @Russ CSS selectors execute faster, their syntax is simpler and easier to read, and they are better supported by the browser. That said, XPaths have their place... they are the only way to find an element by contained text and you can do more complicated DOM traversals than you can with CSS selectors. My preference is ID, then 90% of everything else is CSS selectors, then (in the two situations listed above) I use XPaths.

Comment: @Russ I apologize for asking lot of questions. I understood that, .fircAT > div:nth-child(2) use to find the player statistics tab, after studying your answer. From that could you explain how you extract only the results in summary tab? Because I am curious of extending your method to scrape other tabs like attack, defense also. Thank you again

Comment: The web developer tools are great. That's how I find which css selector to target. For your example it looks like you could target this `.iiSsIo` selector to get the row of tab options then use `html_children()` to find each tab and then feed the children into a loop that you use to click each tab and extract the table.